# Lack of questions surrounding ordinary life?

Tags: discussion, moderation

According to the Help Center,

> If your question is about:
>
> 1. Complications in every day life due to living in a foreign country as a non-citizen
> 2. Questions about long term (1 year+) work and residence visas, permanent residence, and nationality programs ...
> 3. Questions about what laws in your home country apply to you as an expatriate ...
> 4. Questions about laws and governance in your country of residence, that might apply differently to non-citizens than they do to citizens
> 5. Psychological and physical effects of the immigration to a different country, effects of weather, different culture and language
> 6. Education and work seeking questions for a person migrating from a different country
>
> ... then you are probably in the right place to ask your question! Expatriates Stack Exchange is here for **questions surrounding ordinary life**, just complicated by your status as an expatriate (emphasis added and items enumerated).

It seems to me that questions that appear in this site have not been equally distributed across all the six suggested topics above. My impression is that this site primarily deals with topics 2, 3, and 4. This is reflected, for instance, in questions tagged taxes and visas dominating the lot. On the other hand, questions on topics 1, 5, and 6 have featured less and some of these, if they appear, have been disputed.

I am not sure if this is a real problem, but I fear that we have perhaps been too strict?

Comment: I think this is really important and needs to be thought about.

Answer (score 2):

> To move the discussion along, I'm gathering some data for you guys to mull over. I am not making a judgment one way or the other at this point, just figure that you may benefit from somewhere to start discussing from, or where to start looking for questions of these types.

There are currently [38 non-deleted closed questions that aren't duplicates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Atrue+duplicate%3Afalse). I went through each and if I thought it was closed despite being on topic 1, 5, or 6, I put the link under that heading.

Only two were closed as off-topic (`Comment = 102` in the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/expatriates/revision/195829/253388)) that fell in these categories by my count:

- [Whats the process like for buying a car/ getting a driving licence in California?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/601/whats-the-process-like-for-buying-a-car-getting-a-driving-licence-in-california)
- [How do degrees work in Ukraine?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/102/how-do-degrees-work-in-ukraine)

From the data alone, we can say one of two things (assuming my categorization is correct). Either we do not close too many questions in these categories as off-topic, or we are closing these questions as off-topic but not using the right reason when we close.

#### 1. Complications in every day life due to living in a foreign country as a non-citizen

2. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/950/how-difficult-is-it-to-find-an-apartment-flat-or-a-rental-place-in-sweden-for-a
3. [Whats the process like for buying a car/ getting a driving licence in California?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/601/whats-the-process-like-for-buying-a-car-getting-a-driving-licence-in-california)

#### 5. Psychological and physical effects of the immigration to a different country, effects of weather, different culture and language

1. [How to decide between meeting expats versus assimilation?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/how-to-decide-between-meeting-expats-versus-assimilation)
2. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/745/criticizing-taxes-state-policy-etc-cultural-differences-germany-western-eu
3. [US Common Practices with kids that new Immigrant parents should be aware of](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/424/us-common-practices-with-kids-that-new-immigrant-parents-should-be-aware-of)
4. [How do I deal with cultural differences?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/255/how-do-i-deal-with-cultural-differences)

#### 6. Education and work seeking questions for a person migrating from a different country

1. [American C# developer looking to move to EU](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/593/american-c-developer-looking-to-move-to-eu)
2. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/freelance-in-usa-freelance-vs-company
3. [In which countries can a US citizen stay permanently (preferrably free)?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/602/in-which-countries-can-a-us-citizen-stay-permanently-preferrably-free)
4. [How do degrees work in Ukraine?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/102/how-do-degrees-work-in-ukraine)
5. [Should I find consulting contracts before or after moving to the UK?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/should-i-find-consulting-contracts-before-or-after-moving-to-the-uk)
6. [What restrictions exist for a KITAS Holder in Indonesia starting a business?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/349/what-restrictions-exist-for-a-kitas-holder-in-indonesia-starting-a-business)
7. [What is the easiest way to move to New York from the UK?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/774/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-move-to-new-york-from-the-uk)
8. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/unskilled-work-in-europe

Comment: Most of the questions here were closed as too broad, opinion based, or unclear. I revisited each of them, and I think the KITAS one is the only where the close-hammer might have struct too early, but even there the question would have needed a bit more polish (the answer is fine though)

Comment: Definitely not saying they shouldn't have been closed (I don't think you're necessarily making that assumption, just want to be clear). I found it helpful on [workplace.se] to take a look at the data as a base for the discussion because concrete examples for people to read through helps focus the discussion on actual questions rather than hypotheticals. Hopefully it helped!